# Can't finish my ER diagram

Tags: database-design

I am trying to create a database for a small book library. This is not a professional project, just an exercise of my own. This is my first time to try this ( I am self-taught ) and I am encountering a problem. Before I continue I will provide my version of the ER diagram below ( I made it in Paint, using the [following resource](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/a81358/05_dev1.htm) for notation ):

[image]

My biggest problem is to solve the fact that book can have the same title but have several editions or be a part of a set. An example would be *Lord of the Rings* trilogy, or *Programming Windows, 5th edition*, or *Encyclopaedia of chess openings, volume D*.

I don't know how to incorporate this into my ER diagram so that I can avoid data redundancy.

Therefore I ask these questions:

- How should I address the fact that book can have the same title but have several editions or be a part of a set, in my ER diagram?
- Since I am inexperienced, can you point out mistakes in my ER diagram, if there are any, and suggest an improvement?

Since this is my very first post here, please leave a comment if anything needs to be changed ( if it doesn't fit this site's question format ) or if you need further info.

Thank you.

Comment: You should go and take a closer look at the ERD reference that you linked.  I'm pretty sure you have the crow's foot backwards for what you intend.  Your diagram says _"a book has one or more publishers"_ (which may be true in some real world scenarios) **but** it also says: _"a publisher publishes (exactly) one book"_ which I'm sure you didn't mean.  Same thing for members renting and authors writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you look at your model and you consider the requirements that it doesn't handle (i.e. your questions) then you will find that you need to expand your model somewhat.  Consider the following ERD:

(Note I use the James Martin [crows foot notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) which is a little more compact than what you have used but should be pretty simple to understand.  The only slightly distinct feature is the use of an upper case "I" to indicate that a relationship is part of the identifier of the entity)

[image: ERD]

Here are some points that this ERD addresses:

- A `BOOK` which can be rented is a physical thing (assuming you're dealing with paper books).  That means that you need to allow for having *more than one copy*.  Therefore a book has a title, but it isn't the same thing as the title, so my model makes `TITLE` its own entity.
- Depending on whether you want a snapshot of which books are rented and to whom or whether you want an audit trail of which books have been rented to whom, you need to have either a 0,1-to-many or a many-to-many relationship to represent the rental status of each (physical) book.
- Each `BOOK` has an `EDITION`.  This doesn't have to be a special edition.  It could be first edition, paperback, special edition, etc. etc.
- An `EDITION` will have a `TITLE`.  Every edition of the same book will have the same title so the relationship to `TITLE` belongs at the `EDITION` level.
- Similarly, every edition will be published by the same publisher (or group of publishers) whereas different editions may have different publishers.  Since you can have more than one publisher, this needs to have a many-to-many relationship between `PUBLISHER` and `EDITION`.
- A `TITLE` can have multiple authors, so a many-to-many relationship is required between `TITLE` and `WRITER`.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is so clear and comprehensive. I have upvoted it, and am seriously considering to officially accept it. I will do so after studying your ER diagram for a while. Best regards.

Comment: I have officially accepted your answer as I believe it is the most comprehensive one, with the clearest explanation provided. Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that an *Edition* is an entity that is related to a *Book*.

You then have a one-to-many relationship between Books and Editions.  (One book can have many editions.)  and a many-to-one relationship between Editions and Publishers  (many editions are published by one publisher).

When I was building actual databases, back in the day, I always had access to one or more "subject matter experts",  people who had become familiar with the data through constant use.  Most subject matter experts were neither computer experts nor database experts.  Your situation is somewhat different.

I would try to find some kind of on line subject matter expert, like the Library of Congress.  They might have some kind of model of the publishing industry that would provide answers to this and other questions you have regarding how the field of publishing really works.  And this model might be in the public domain.

PS:  Congratulations on using the ER model as an analysis tool,  and not diving into database design prematurely.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have tried with online search but all of the diagrams I found were poorly designed in my opinion: they all assumed there was only one publisher and only one writer, along with similar simplifications. I will try out to Google about your suggestion for Library of Congress. Best regards.

Comment: You have to distinguish between poor design and poor analysis.  Poor design involves setting up the wrong tables with the wrong components and rules.  Poor analysis involves a misunderstanding of the underlying subject matter.   Library science is a well established field,  and the librarians know an awful lot about it, even in the face of today's rapid changes.  These are your subject matter experts, not some whiz bang database designers.  Good luck with the search.

Answer (score 1):

I see one design possible with your reqirement as

`Book` Table

```
BookId PK
WriterId -FK
PublisherId -FK
Title
..Other columns
```

`Editions` Table

```
EditionId - PK
BookId - FK
..Other Columns
```

`Sets` Table

```
SetsId - PK
EditionsId - FK
VolumnName-- Like A, B(or 1,2)
```

Now I see one problem with above design, Let say with new editions if publisher changed, then `PublisherId` clumns can be better moved to `Editions` tables to provide such flexibility in future, same with `writerId` or incase of multiple `writerId`, you can choose to add one more table to save `writerId` with `editionsId`. Choose `INT/BigInt` for Id column.

Comment: Thank you for your help,I will consider everything you said and report my results as soon as possible. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what information you want to store about the edition. You
   could add another table with an `Edition` column and a `Book_ID`
   foreign key. (e.g. an Edition *has a* Book)

With sets, you could have another couple of tables. One with a `Set_ID` column and a `Set` column; and another table with a `Set_ID` column and a `Book_ID` column.

For example -

```
Set_ID  Set
1       Lord of the Rings Trilogy 

Set_ID  Book_ID 
1       1 
1       2 
1       3

Book_ID Book 
1       The Fellowship of the Ring
2       The Two Towers
3       The Return of the King
```

Does that make sense?

Apologies for not drawing the diagram, I'm not familiar with them :)

Comment: *Apologies for not drawing the diagram, I'm not familiar with them :)* No problem. *Does that make sense?* Yes it does. I will wait for a while before accepting officially, to see if some other answers will come up. Thank you for your help. Best regards.

Comment: No worries, I hope that helps!